# Traveling without the EU spouse!

Tags: italy, sweden, eu-spouses

I'm non-EU spouse of an EU (Italian) citizen. I have a residence card issued by the Italian authorities, stating that I'm a non-EU family member. My question is can I travel to Sweden without my spouse and stay up to 90 days there?

Comment: I assume you are not a citizen of a visa-exempt country.  My understanding is that Sweden can require you to hold a visa if you travel without your spouse.  Apply for one.  They're unlikely to deny it, given your circumstances.

Comment: @phoog but a residency permit from a Schengen country allows you to visit another Schengen member state for up to 90 days!

Comment: @SayedA. Hm. You are right. Perhaps you should add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

On [http://ec.europa.eu](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm)

> **Visa exemptions**
>
> Your non-EU spouse, (grand)children or (grand)parents do not need to
> get a visa from the country they are travelling to if:
>
> - They have a residence permit or visa from another country in the
>   border-free Schengen area (see list below) and the country they are
>   travelling to belongs to that area.
>
> [image]
>
> NB: Residence permits issued by countries outside the Schengen area do
> not allow non-EU family members to travel visa-free to a Schengen area
> country.

So to answer your question, NO, you don't need visa to travel to Sweden for up to 90 days in any 180 days period!

This assumes, however, that you haven't been in other Schengen countries.  Strictly speaking, with a residence permit you're still only allowed 90 days in any 180-day period in the Schengen area, not counting days when in the country that issued the permit.  In practice, though, there's no way to enforce this easily, because border crossings in the Schengen area are not tracked.

(As an aside, the 90/180 rule does not apply when you are traveling with your EU family member; in that case you fall under the freedom of movement directive.)

Comment: You're right, I answered according to the OP's situation since he mentioned he is travelling without his spouse, you can edit my answer and add your comment as it might be useful!

Answer (score -5):

Yes. Up to 90 days in any EU country. You could go to Norway for a day and do another 90, really, if you'd like.

But don't ask important questions like these on the web. Ask the [proper authorities](http://www.migrationsverket.se/)

Comment: Sorry, the 90 days is for travel without a visa if you are a citizen of a visa exempt country. Since you have a residence permit in the EU you can go wherever you like in the EEA and Switzerland. But don't take my word for it, ask the authorities.

Comment: [Here it is.](http://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/EU-citizens-and-long-term-residents/Work-study-or-live-in-Sweden-for-EU-citizens/Residence-cards-for-family-who-are-non-EU-citizens.html)

Comment: Again, that's wrong in several ways **and your link confirms that**. Can you please take some time to actually read the material you are quoting before spreading more misinformation?

Comment: From the website: "If your family are non-EU citizens and you intend to stay in Sweden for more than three months, the family members should apply for residence cards at the Swedish Migration Agency."

That means that if you intend to stay less than 90 days, you need not apply for a permit, only your residence permit in another EU country.

Comment: No, that's not what it means. Because you might need to apply for a visa (and it says that in the very next section of the page). It is however true that a residence permit from another *Schengen* (but not “EU”) country would exempt you from this visa requirement in Sweden (which is a Schengen country). Similarly, it does not apply to non-Schengen EU countries like the UK (where a visa might be required) and is distinct from the EU freedom of movement right to stay 90 days without residence permit in each country (which only applies if you are travelling *with* your EU spouse).

Comment: The distinction between the two is what makes the question complicated. Your answer does not address that issue and is unhelpful.

Comment: But the question is specific to Sweden. And as I say, don't trust know-it-alls the web, ask the proper authorities.

Comment: Fair enough but you did write “any EU country”, not Sweden. And “ask the authorities” is less helpful than you might think and is at best a comment.